# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list IBM .net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, db2

I am tying to use IBM DB .NET Provider for MS .NET Core and no matter what I do with creating my context every time I try to use it I get the following error.

"Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Context Class

```
    public class IBMContext : DbContext
    {

        public IBMContext()
            : base()
        {
        }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

        optionsBuilder.UseDb2(@"Server=server;Database=DB;userid=user;password=pass",
            p => p.SetServerInfo(IBMDBServerType.AS400, IBMDBServerVersion.AS400_07_01));

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Table> Table{ get; set; }

}
```

Model.cs

```
[Table("Table")]
public class Table
{
    [Key]
    public int Key{ get; set; }

    public string Stat{ get; set; }

    public string Jul{ get; set; }

    public string App { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

}
```

Use

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");

        var context = new IBMContext();

        var result = context.Table.ToList();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Package

IBM.EnityFrameworkCore(1.1.1.101)

Full Error Stack

System.FormatException occurred
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
  Source=
  StackTrace:
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, String& szConnectionString, DB2ConnSettings& ppSettings, Object& ppConn)
   at IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Connection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_ShapedQuery>d__3`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at IBMEntityFrameworkCoreTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\CodeBase\IBMEntityFrameworkCoreTest\IBMEntityFrameworkCoreTest\Program.cs:line 24

Comment: Can you tell me what port do you usually use to connect to AS400? I normally get a communication error using DB2 for Iseries

Comment: @AnaFranco It is normally 446. What are the details of the error you are getting?

Comment: I get a licence error but I believe I have everything in order, I Even can connect using data studio or excel

Comment: I'm going to try this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21635635 Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out that this is caused by have another version of driver from IBM entered in my environment variable Path. You can test what Visual Studio is looking at by running a Visual Studio Command Prompt and typing

```
db2level
```

I had

```
C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\IBMDAT~1\BIN
```

You need to remove this and make sure you have

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\.nuget\packages\IBM.Data.DB2.Core\1.1.1.101\build\clidriver"
```

The command you need to run to update the path variable

```
Set PATH=%PATH%;(your new path);
```

You can find out more information about this at

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9a107d00-d814-440c-b438-faa4d020ae1a&ps=25